# How to load .png images from Documents folder of an app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image

I have .png images in the Documents folder of my app but when i try to load them it don't work :/

I have this class for the methods for saving and loading :

UIImage+loadScan.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (loadScan)

- (void)saveScan:(NSString*)name;

- (UIImage *)loadScan:(NSString*)name;

@end
```

.m :

```
#import "UIImage+loadScan.h"

@implementation UIImage (loadScan)

#pragma SAVE AND LOAD

- (void)saveScan:(NSString*)name{
    if (self != nil)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          [NSString stringWithString:name] ];
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}

- (UIImage *)loadScan:(NSString*)name{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, name];
    NSLog(@"loading %@", path);

    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];

    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return image;
}

@end
```

The method saveScan work good :

```
[image saveScan:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imgName]];
```

But loadScan don't want to work :

```
UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] init];
[imageLoad loadScan:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imgName]];
cell.imageScan.image = imageLoad;
```

I don't understand why, yet the file exist.

Thanks

Comment: Here What is the ImageName Means imgName always same ? r u check the images are saved in document folder

Comment: Define "don't work".

Comment: I have checked in the "Documents" folder (with iFunBox), the .png really exist.
I have an image for each cell of my UITableView, but image don't appear. imgName is a NSString of the name of the image file without extention.
My code work if i store the image in an array like : `cell.imageScan.image = theScan[19];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a (strange) method, but it work (i send the UIImage also un parametter and init it in the method) :

```
- (UIImage *)loadScan:(NSString*)name theImage:(UIImage*)theImg{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, name];
    NSLog(@"loading %@", path);

    [theImg initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return theImg;
}
```

Call with :

```
UIImage *imageLoad = [UIImage alloc];
            [imageLoad loadScan:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@2x.png", imgName] theImage:imageLoad];
```

Now imageLoad have the image data and we can show it !